# Did I understand the fuel economy of my boat correctly?

Tags: boats, fuel, outboard-engine

I don't know anything about outdoor sports or anything beyond the downtown of my metropolitan city.  But someone gifted me a boat (along with piece of land in the middle of no where) and I'm trying to learn more about it.  I've done some research online about the boat, but I'm not confident if I have the correct information, and want to run these details by people to see if anything I've stated is incorrect.

The only thing I'm confident about the boat is that I see it is a Year 2019 Campion Allante 535 BR with a Yamaha Sho 115 Outboard engine.  That's the only thing I know for certain.

Based on that, I think the fuel tank capacity is 87 Litres (or 23 Gallons).  People say that the engine can use 87oct gasoline, which is the same as what I put in my Toyota Corolla.  A full tank of gasoline in the boat will last me a maximum of 6 hours when traveling at a speed of 10km/hr.   (Corrected speedto 10 km/hr in response to comments.)

Does that seem correct?

---

Comment: Are you sure you can go 30 km/h? In the area I live many of the waterways have much lower restrictions (10 km/h) and many boats do not go much faster even when there are no limits.

Comment: @Willeke  - you are probably right!  You know more than me.  Some of the numbers I threw out ther eare based on calculations I wrote on an envelope , which might be based on incorrect inforamtion it he first place. I updated my question!

Comment: So how long *did* the boat go on a tank of gas? Was it 2 hours or 6 hours?

Comment: @WeatherVane - I don't know. I've never used the boat before. I don'te ven know how to turn it on.  I calculated 2 hrs assuming a velocity of 30km/hr.  So then i multiply 2hr by 3 if going 10km/hr.  Hopefully i did the math right?

Comment: and the person who gifted me all these things disappeared off the face of the planet.  And i don't have any friends who konws anything about boats.  So assume I'm a 2 year old who knows nothing about anything about boats or water or trees and stuff.

Comment: [This site](https://fishtalkmag.com/blog/yamaha-outboards-mid-sized-motors-f115-and-f150) says *"the F115 cruises at 27 MPH while spinning 4500 rpm; at this speed it gets **4.7 mpg**. At wide-open throttle, the F115 propels the Dominator to 39 mph and gets **3.8 mpg**."* This isn't a dawdling pleasure craft but a power boat.

Comment: Ok, so 27MPH is like a corolla driving through a neighbourhood type of speed.  And at that speed, a full tank can last about 4 hours or so (as opposed to 30 minutes, which is what another friend was telling me).  So it's not like I have to be constantly refuelling through out the day just to get from point A to point B.  Does tat sound about right?

Comment: No: this is no Toyota Corolla. Relatively 27 mph on water is like driving through a neighbourhood at 60 mph. And at full chat that could be a supercar doing the ton on residential streets. I recommend you check out the rules of the river where it will be used: licenses for the boat and its driver; speed limits; education requirements; safety rules; certificates... *"assume I'm a 2 year old who knows nothing about anything about boats or water or trees"*. It's time to wise up, before you cause damage to people, places or yourself.

Comment: Makes sense.  I'm actually trying to sell.  I want to know enough to speak intelligently about it to buyers AND Im trying to convince my family how ridiculously expensive it is to keep, maintain or even attempt to use this vehicle, and we don't want this kind of burden. And now there is the danger reason too, so we really need to get rid of it.  This helps me better understand!

Comment: Good luck to you, perhaps you can contact a trader.

Comment: @John There's an old saying "*a boat is a hole in the water you pour money into*". Its not strictly true, but they can be expensive to maintain and use. I would make inquiries at boat shops about re-selling.

Comment: Interest rates canada are also very high too.  Better to put that money against debts than risk our lives on water activities.  Yup will reach out to dealers too to see roughly how much of a cut they get vs me learning enough to sell it